# search in array values - powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell

I've an array with 10 values (0 to 9). Each array value output is a multi-liner. Here is what it looks like for example -

```
C:>arrval[0]
12345
34593433598434
error1
357948557
C:>arrval[1]
238296879234
error1
93454753503
error2
```

I'm checking to see if we can print only the error portion in an array value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$arrval -split "`n" |  where {$_ -like "*error*"}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying! It prints the whole array value. I'm already filtering the array values using `Select-String`. It results only the array values that has errors.

Comment: Put an output example please

Comment: Please ignore the above comment. I accidentally hit enter.
Here is an output example -
error1
error1
error2

Comment: Sorry, yes. I agree! I was using `foreach ($error in $arrval){ $error -split "`n" | where {$_ -like "*error*"}}`. In this scenario, $error.gettype() returns `system.object` where `$arrval.gettype()` returns `System.Array`. Looks like that's the problem? :|